# jQuery/JSON data not looping in created HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Currently trying to loop through a JSON file and for each object, create a article tag around the data as I format it with HTML, I am successful and creating the first article tag but the I cannot loop through to the next object with the $.each function

HTML code

```
    <body>
          <div id='container'>
       <div id='content'>
        <article class='tumblrPost'>
         <header>
         <h1> Dragonball Z Motivation </h1>
         </header>
         <img src='images/dragonball_z.jpg' alt='dragonball z' title='dbz' />
         <footer>
            <h1> Watch the Video Life & Motivation with Dragonball Z </h1>
        </footer>
        </article>
       </div>
       </div>
       </body>
      </html>
```

('document').ready(function() {
    getPosts();
    });

```
function getPosts() {
var articlePosts = $('div#content article');
    $.getJSON('animeTest.json', function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                output = "<article>";
                output += "<header>";
                output += "<h1>" + val.header + "</h1>";
                output += "</header>";
                output += "<img src='images/" + val.image + "' title='image' />";
                output += "<footer>";
                output += "<h1>" + val.footer + "</h1>";
                output += "</footer>";
                output += "</article>"; 
        }); 
                articlePosts.last().after(output);
    });
}
```

Comment: What does `data` look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are overwriting output on each cycle

```
 output = "<article>";
```

Quick fix: try appending the content inside the loop cycle too (and don't declare a global)

```
$.each(data, function(key, val) {
            var output = "<article>";
            output += "<header>";
            output += "<h1>" + val.header + "</h1>";
            output += "</header>";
            output += "<img src='images/" + val.image + "' title='image' />";
            output += "<footer>";
            output += "<h1>" + val.footer + "</h1>";
            output += "</footer>";
            output += "</article>"; 
            articlePosts.last().after(output);
    });
```

BTW, I feel more comfortable operating on jQuery elements instead of concatenating html. You should try it!

```
var output = $('<article></article');
var header= $('<header></header');
header.append("<h1>" + val.header + "</h1>").appendTo(output);

output.append("<img src='images/" + val.image + "' title='image' />");

var footer= $ ('<footer></footer>');
footer.append("<h1>" + val.footer + "</h1>").appendTo(output);

articlePosts.last().after(output);
```

it saves you the pain of closing tags

Answer (score 2):

You're resetting `output` on each iteration. Technically, you are probably only seeing the *last* result shown as an article in the HTML.

Instead, declare `output` right before `$.each()`, and then only ever append to it. Once you're done looping, append the entire result to your page:

```
function getPosts() {
    var articlePosts = $('div#content article');
    $.getJSON('animeTest.json', function(data) {
        var output = ''; // make sure you use 'var' so it's not a global variable
        $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                output += "<article>";
                output += "<header>";
                output += "<h1>" + val.header + "</h1>";
                output += "</header>";
                output += "<img src='images/" + val.image + "' title='image' />";
                output += "<footer>";
                output += "<h1>" + val.footer + "</h1>";
                output += "</footer>";
                output += "</article>"; 
        }); 
        articlePosts.last().after(output);
    });
}
```

Lastly, if you find yourself building HTML like this often, I would suggest looking into various HTML/JavaScript templating solutions. They would make your JavaScript code far cleaner and easier to maintain by keeping your HTML and JavaScript separate.

Comment: Upvote - correctly declared and initialised the variable output